# Прерывное подключение бота к серверу

Tags: python, aiogram

Бот написан с использованием библиотеки aiogram.
Проблема заключается в том, что после запуска бота, через некоторое количество часов, pycharm начинает выкидывать ошибки. Точно не могу понять, это как-то я облажался с с лупом или все же сам сервер, где запущен бот, переодически отключается, что и выдает такие логи.

```
WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.


ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 560, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 899, in start
    message, payload = await protocol.read()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 616, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [WinError 64] Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientOSError: [WinError 64] Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 560, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 899, in start
    message, payload = await protocol.read()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 616, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [WinError 64] Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientOSError: [WinError 64] Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно




ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

Хотя после всех этих ошибок бот продолжает работать, однако в моментах он прекращает работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я случайно поставил `skip_updates=True`. При смене на `False` ошибки пропадают:

```
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```